# low disk space on filesystem root fedora 32

Tags: fedora, disk-usage

Today my Fedora 32 operation system give me tips that : `low disk space on filesystem root fedora`:

[image]

this tips make me surprise,with my limit experience,not like windows partition, the linux root system contains all file system,I have 1TB SDD and I am very sure the disk space is low pressure.what should I do to fix this problem? why the root not using `/dolphin/home` folder space? the are different space like window C system partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost 70 GB of data in your root partition? That does not look normal, so it's possible that you are using it for the wrong purpose.

[Older Fedora versions](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-x86.html) recommended 3 to 5 GB for the root partition:

> A 3.0 GB partition allows you to install a minimal installation, while a 5.0 GB root partition lets you perform a full installation, choosing all package groups.

The [requirements have been lifted](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f32/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda/#) in more recent versions, but still far from the size that you allocated:

> For a minimal installation, a 5 GB root partition will be sufficient. However, for most common installations which include extra packages and a graphical user interface, the root partition should be at least 10 GB; with 20 GB being sufficient for most common use cases.

So the question is really: what are you storing in there? Without any additional information, I can only suggest to check your `/var` folder, perhaps especially the `/var/cache` folder. But generally speaking it's likely that your problem is your `/var` folder.

Comment: Yes,you are right. I am install 3 kvm virtual machine and using much space in var folder.I have moved the image files to home folder now.@user1301428

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you decided not to partition when you built your machine and threw everything into the same partition. This can cause problems when you run out of space.

I would recommend checking out [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) or [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu).

Comment: Thank you,I install a qdirstat using `sudo dnf install qdirstat` and file the kvm image files take too much space of my root disk.@Aaron D. Marasco